# How are chemicals prilled?

Tags: elements

What does the process of prilling something like, say, calcium nitrate, involve? Do you need other chemicals to prill the substance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prill

Comment: @Mithoron I saw the Wikipedia article already, although it's nice to link for reference. I didn't see any mention of whether other chemicals are required to make the process possible, however (for instance, anything else besides calcium nitrate).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer for sure, but will take a guess based on what I read at the link provided by Mithoron.

Non-chemists outside the laboratory, and persons who have to handle and work with those chemicals would certainly benefit from prilling to reduce dusting which could be detrimental to their health in breathing and on the mucous membranes.

Gardeners use Ammonium, potassium and calcium nitrates in fertilizers and stump removers, and do not always wear eye protection or dust masks. Thus prilling helps to mitigate exposure to these chemicals.